# HTML Tidy license question

Tags: html, licensing, htmltidy

I'm looking to use the HTML Tidy source code and modify it to add a few more features. Having read the [license](http://tidy.cvs.sourceforge.net/tidy/tidy/include/tidy.h?view=markup), I'm not quite sure if I will *have to* release the source of my modified application? I don't want to.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to. This is just a normal [BSD-style licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).

Comment: No, its MIT-style license. Erm...are you sure?

Comment: The MIT licence is a "BSD-style licence".